# The desire for more light than what the led allows... or can that be used to light something else?

Tags: led-driver

What would be a cheap and dirty way to use the illuminated led circuit that indicates which side of a chess timer is counting down to drive a better indicator? For example, a larger bank of leds or what have you.

I know that there is not a lot there to switch a relay and my brain is other projects that need more attention at the moment so I thought I'd ask the collective.

[image]

Comment: Anything that can drive a LED can also drive a BJT, which can then handle much more current than the original LED circuit. Do you have any details about the clock's circuitry at all? Or glue a photocell to the LED and use that to control whatever you  want.

Comment: Dave nailed things very well. But physics is fun and just to throw your mind in a radically different direction, take a look at: [direct optical amplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_amplifier). After reading that, it's back to what Dave said. That's the practical approach. But you will need to explore the details of the circuit  surrounding that light (and the other one.) Without a schematic, you'll need a few tools -- perhaps most importantly, a willingness to open it up and use your eyes. Plus a multimeter of some kind.

Comment: camera with a big screen TV